# Is it possible to sandbox an ASP.Net site on IIS7.5 without using Medium Trust?

Tags: asp.net, full-trust

Setting the .Net trust level to Medium on a site will ensure that no code can access files outside the application directory.

I have an ASP.Net site that must run in Full Trust.  I have configured my website in IIS to use its own  [Application Pool Identity](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) (IIS Apppool\www.site-name.com).

Currently it is possible for scripts/code in this app to read files outside of the application directory.  This occurs because by default, accounts that are a member of the BUILTIN\users group are able to read most files on the system, including c:\ and c:\windows.  It appears that Applicaion Pool Identity accounts are also members of BUILTIN\users.

Is it possible to prevent file access outside the website folder while keeping Full Trust?

Answer (score 0):

How about using file/directory ACL to deny your AppPoolIdentity access to needed folders?